# Ordered sort in STL containers

Tags: c++, algorithm

Sorry if the question title  terminology is wrong, but here is what I want to do.I need to sort a vector of objects, but contrary to a [typical comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) "less than" approach I need to re-position the objects based on some  string ID property so that each same type members are positioned in consecutive order like this:

```
[id_town,id_country,id_planet,id_planet,id_town,id_country]
```

becomes this:

```
[id_town,id_town,id_country,id_country,id_planet,id_planet]
```

id_ property is string.

Comment: `std::sort` takes a comparison predicate as its third parameter. Just write a suitable one.

Comment: Are all these id's in a container ?

Comment: The ids are properties of the objects in the container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) has a third parameter which can be used to pass a boolean predicate that acts as custom comparator. **Write your own comparator acording to your specifications and use it.**

For example:

```
struct foo
{
    std::string id;

    foo(const std::string& _id) : id( _id ) {}
};

//Functor to compare foo instances:
struct foo_comparator
{
    operator bool(const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> v;

    std::sort( std::begin(v) , std::end(v) , foo_comparator );
}
```

Also, in C++11 you could use a lambda:

```
std::sort( std::begin(v) , std::end(v) , [](const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs) { return lhs.id < rhs.id; } );
```

Finally, you can also overload the comparison operators (`operator>` and `operator<`) and use comparators provided by the standard library like [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater):

```
struct foo
{
    std::string id;

    foo(const std::string& _id) : id( _id ) {}

    friend bool operator<(const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }

    friend bool operator>(const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs)
    {
        return rhs < lhs;
    }

    friend bool operator>=(const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs < rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator<=(const foo& lhs , const foo& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs > rhs);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> v;

    std::sort( std::begin(v) , std::end(v) , std::greater );
}
```

Comment: @MichaelIV Note that the utilities library provides the implementation of all relational operators based on `operator==` and `operator<`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp, so if you include that libray you only have to write that two last operators.

Comment: Great!Thanks!Read about functors once but never realized how useful these can be.

Comment: @MichaelIV you do not have to include (`using` sentence) the `std::rel_ops` namespace, because the overloads will be finded through [*Argumment Dependent Lookup* (ADL)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3623643/1609356)

Comment: Shouldn't you pass an object instead of class? That is,`sort(begin(v), end(v), foo_comparator())`