# sorting std vector of strings without using default algorithm

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I have an `std::vector` of `std::strings`, each of which is a filename. Suppose filenames are of the format `some_name_n.xyz`.

The problem is that `some_name_10.xyz` is less than `some_name_2.xyz`. The files are produced by some other process.

What is the least painful way to sort them so that the number after '_' is considered for comparison, and not just its length?

Comment: You can simply rename them to be like `'_%04d'`.

Comment: Write your own comparator functor and pass it to sort?

Comment: And why `without using default algorithm`? What `default algorithm`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao the default algorithm does not work. some_name_2 will be greater than some_name_10. I want it to be less.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Because it will sort file_10.xyz before file_2.xyz.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I cannot rename the files for other reasons

Comment: I see. Then you just need to write your own `compare` function to pass it to `sort()`.

Comment: could you provide an example for std::vector<string>? I'm not sure if I understand how to do it... Thank you.

Comment: Check out the following answers for references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ordered sort in STL containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659882/ordered-sort-in-stl-containers)

Comment: @Manu343726: that's not a duplicate at all... it requires a normal "<" comparison for a specific field in the structures being sorted, whereas this one needs special handling of embedded numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::sort` allows you to specify a binary function for comparing two elements: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Now it's just a matter of constructing that binary function. A partial example is here: [Sorting std::strings with numbers in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622516/sorting-stdstrings-with-numbers-in-them)

Answer (score 1):

The least painful way is to put approporiate leading zeroes into your file names (even writing a second script that takes the generated names and renames them may be easier than writing your own sort routine).

The second least painful way is to write your own sort predicate that does sorts `_` delimited numbers as a number rather than lexicographically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comparison that handles any number of numeric values embedded in the strings:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef  _MSC_VER
#define strtoll _strtoi64
#endif

int cmp(const char* lhs, const char* rhs)
{
    while (*lhs || *rhs)
    {
        if (isdigit(*lhs) && isdigit(*rhs))
        {
            char* l_end;
            char* r_end;
            long long l = strtoll(lhs, &l_end, 10);
            long long r = strtoll(rhs, &r_end, 10);
            if (l < r) return -1;
            if (l > r) return 1;
            lhs = l_end;
            rhs = r_end;
        }
        else
            if (*lhs != *rhs)
                return *lhs - *rhs;
            else
                ++lhs, ++rhs;
    }
    return *lhs - *rhs;
}
```

It's deliberately "C style" so it can be applied directly and efficiently to character arrays.  It returns a negative number if `lhs < rhs`, 0 if they're equal, and a positive number if `lhs > rhs`.

You can call this from a comparison functor or lambda specified to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom comparator something like following :

```
struct Comp{

    auto get_num (const std::string& a)
    {
        auto it1 = std::find_if( a.begin(), a.end(), ::isdigit );
        auto it2 = std::find_if( a.begin(), a.end(), 
                               [](char x){ return x == '.' ;}) ;
        /* Do some checks here for std::string::npos*/
        auto pos1 = std::distance( a.begin(), it1) ;
        auto pos2 = std::distance( it1, it2) ;
        return std::stoi (a.substr( pos1, pos2 )) ;
    }

    bool operator () (const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
        return get_num (a) < get_num (b) ;
    }

};
```

See demo [here](http://ideone.com/4FnXrp)