# Why overloaded operator== for std::weak_ptr instantiated with type defined in namespace can't be found?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Any idea why this code compiles:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo;
class Bar;
typedef std::pair<Foo*,std::weak_ptr<Bar>> Object;
typedef std::vector<Object> ObjectVect;

bool operator==( std::weak_ptr<Bar> left,
                 std::weak_ptr<Bar> right )
{
    return left.lock() == right.lock();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    ObjectVect vect;
    Object obj;
    auto foundIter = std::find( vect.begin(), vect.end(), obj );
    return 0;
}
```

while this one gives me error:

```
#include <memory>

class Foo;
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Bar;
}
typedef std::pair<Foo*,std::weak_ptr<MyNamespace::Bar>> Object;
typedef std::vector<Object> ObjectVect;

bool operator==( std::weak_ptr<MyNamespace::Bar> left,
                 std::weak_ptr<MyNamespace::Bar> right )
{
    return left.lock() == right.lock();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    ObjectVect vect;
    Object obj;
    auto foundIter = std::find( vect.begin(), vect.end(), obj );
    return 0;
}
```

> Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand
>   operand of type 'const std::weak_ptr' (or there is
>   no acceptable
>   conversion)   test_cppunit_interpreter_base_multi_output  c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\utility   216

Looks like it failes to find the comparator when `Bar` is located in a namespace...

Am I doing something wrong? Or could this be a compiler bug?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623643/2550156

_You should put the operator overload in the same namespace as your class._

Comment: Namespaces that contain a type, should include the free functions of that type as well. So to answer *"Am I doing something wrong?"*, I'd say you are using namespaces wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller The free function works on `std::weak_ptr<Bar>`, which is **not** a type contained in `namespace MyNamespace`.

Comment: @Walter - It is contained there, in the second sample.

Comment: @StoryTeller NO, it is not, only `Bar` is.

Comment: @Walter - The *it* is Bar.

Comment: @Walter - And frankly, I have no Idea what you are arguing for. The first example is proper use of namespace (by omission, both type and free function are in the global namespace). And the second is **imporper** use of namespaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should move `operator==` into the namespace to make [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) take effect; ADL will also examine the types used as the template arguments (i.e. `MyNamespace::Bar`) and add the associated namespaces (i.e `MyNamespace`) to the set of name lookup.
i.e.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class Bar;
    bool operator==( std::weak_ptr<Bar> left,
                     std::weak_ptr<Bar> right )
    {
        return left.lock() == right.lock();
    }

}
```

**Why the 1st case works fine?**

Because ADL works for global namespace too. For the 1st case both `Bar` and `operator==` is defined in the same namespace (i.e. the global namespace).

**Why the 2nd case doesn't work?**

Firstly note that `std::find` is defined in the namespace `std`, and there're many `operator==`s defined in it (with different parameter types). Then according to the rule of [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup), when `operator==` is found at the namespace `std`, the name lookup stops. That means without the help of ADL, the `operator==` defined in the global namespace won't be found at all.

Comment: In this case there is no need to prefix `Bar` with `MyNamespace::`.

Comment: Perhaps you could dare to explain why the `operator==` declared outside of the `namespace` cannot be used, i.e. why ADL is required here. Also, how come ADL works here, since arguably `std::weak_ptr<>` is in `std`, not `MyNamespace`.

Comment: At least it heps me having by `find` function work. But I'm not convinced why it be invalid to declare the operator outside the namespace...

Comment: @jpo38 - It's not invalid, just don't expect unqualified lookup to work.

Comment: IMHO a complete answer should explain why unqualified name lookup does not work here.

Comment: @Walter I tried to add the necessary explanations, tell me if something is still not clear. (It takes me some time to confirm why it doesn't work without ADL. And thanks StoryTeller about the hint of unqualified name lookup!)

Comment: Yes, that's great +1!

Comment: This should mention two-phase lookup.